# undefined method error while accessing another controllers method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

My product controller looks like this:

```
class ProductsController < InheritedResources::Base

public
    def product_params(p=params)
      p.require(:product).permit(:manufacturer, :part_no, :avatar)
    end
end
```

`Item` has one to one relationship with product. In `Item`'s controller (activeadmin) cI am doing this:

```
@item.product = Product.create(ProductsController.product_params(params[:item]))
```

And got this error:

```
undefined method `product_params' for ProductsController:Class
```

Now please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please send your full controller code.

Comment: your method is an instance method, but you are calling it as a class method, so try defining the app under `def self.product_params` or try `ProductsController.new.product_params`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady thanks! It worked! :)

Comment: I just noticed that your code is actually in the products controller, no need to do what i wrote above, just use `product_params` directly like proposed in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller implement `product_params` as **instance method**, not like **static class method**.

We have two ways to fix it:

- declare `products_params` as static class method.
- call to `produtcs_params` to current instance.

First option:

```
def self.product_params(p=params)
  p.require(:product).permit(:manufacturer, :part_no, :avatar)
end
```

Second option:

```
@item.product = Product.create(product_params(params[:item]))
```

Answer (score 3):

`product_params` is an instance object method, of the class `ProductsController`

You are calling `product_params` on class `ProductsController`, and such does not exist, `product_params` is not class method it is instance object method, it can only be called on instance object of `ProductsController`